MS Graph API : mail snooze function
I'm currently making mail system using graph api (such as outlook).
Most of them are working fine but I'm struggling to make Snooze function using graph api. (e.g remind me 1hour later)
Anyone know how to use snooze function through graph api?
Thanks
I know there are function to move mail to other folder but I don't think there are setting time option for reminder

How it should work? Postpone the delivery of the message to the end user?

Did you ever manage to build a snooze using MAPI?

I found MAPI for making snooze mark, but I couldn't find MAPI properties for automatically resending for scheduled(snoozed) time.

@ilse2005 do you know the way?

No, not yet.
What is the property for marking it as snooze?

@ilse2005 - it's 'SystemTime 0x0F07' I found it by comparing snooze message using MFCMapi. You can try something like this
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{messageID}/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'SystemTime 0x0F07')

Yes, I tried setting that too. But it only changes to the snoozed view if the email was already snoozed before. Just adding this flag to a new email has no effect

@ilse2005 Yes, you are right. I don't think there is properties for resending snoozed mail.

When you set a reminder / followup on a regular mail message in Outlook, a few MAPI properties are set - you can see them in OutlookSpy (I am its author):

Some (but not all) of these properties can be accessed directly through Graph (see followupFlag):

See if these properties are enough for you. If not, you can always request/set raw MAPI properties through singleValueExtendedProperties. E.g., for the TaskComplete property, you can use
"singleValueExtendedProperties":[{"id":"Boolean {00062003-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x811c","value":"false"}]

